# React Js - Recomendación sobre el desarrollo de un e-commerce

Tags: reactjs

Principalmente, destacar que esto no es una pregunta sobre un problema a resolver como tal; sino una pregunta sobre recomendación.

En esencia estoy desarrollando un ecommerce en React Js, he llevando tiempo en el mismo, lo que me ha permitido darme cuenta que lo estoy creando de una forma muy limitada. El ecommerce cuenta con panel de administración para agregar los productos; en sí, en un inicio lo estuve creando para un producto específico que llevaba ciertas características (tallas, colores); el usuario puede seleccionar la talla, el color e ingresar una cantidad y al presionar agregar al carrito, se efectúan ciertas validaciones para la disponibilidad en stock, de lo solicitado. Después de un tiempo tomé en cuenta que no solo existirán productos con esas especificaciones, sino que solo tengan por ejemplo talla, o solo color; así que tuve que cambiar el panel de administración y la forma en la que se almacenan los datos del producto.

Dado el caso, la forma en que se pintarán los elementos en pantalla será distinto, dependiendo de qué opciones tenga el producto (para que el usuario elija).

De momento, tengo los siguiente; 3 estados uno para la cantidad, color y talla; pero como mencioné previamente no todos los productos tendrán las mismas opciones, por lo que tener esos estados para un producto que no los requiera, sería innecesario y agregar todas las opciones no sería una buena  opción. Lo que necesito es que, por favor, me den su recomendación ara cambiar esto, por algo versátil, que no dependa de las opciones.

```
const PurchaseSection = ({product}) => {
    // Contexts
    const { setShowAlertMsg, setMsg } = useContext(AlertMsgContext)
const { productsToBuy, setProductsToBuy } = useContext(ProductsToBuyContext)

    const [color, setColor] = useState('')
    const [qty, setQty] = useState(1)
    const [size, setSize] = useState('')

    const [msgQty, setMsgQty] = useState('')

    const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false)
    const [purchaseSpecs, setPurchaseSpecs] = useState({})

    return (
        <>
            {showPopup && <PurchasePopup product={purchaseSpecs} setShowPopup={setShowPopup} />}
            <FirstContainer>
                <div>
                    <img src="" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Price: ${product.price}</span>
                </div>
            </FirstContainer>

            <ElementsContainer>
                <InfoSpecsContainer>
                    <InfoContainer>
                        <div>
                            <h1>{product.product_name}</h1>
                            <p>{product.description}</p>
                        </div>
                    </InfoContainer>
                    <SpecsContainer>
                        <Table>
                            {product && product.options && 
                                <Row>
                                    {product.options.map((option) => {
                                        if (option.option === 'color') {
                                             return (
                                                option.values.map((value, id) => {
                                                    if (value.total === 0) {
                                                        return (
                                                            <div key={id}>
                                                                <Button disabled={true} >
                                                                    {value.color}
                                                                </Button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        )
                                                    } else {
                                                        return (
                                                            <div key={id}>
                                                                {color === value.value ? 
                                                                    <Button type={'selected'}>
                                                                        {value.value}
                                                                    </Button>
                                                                :
                                                                    <Button onClick={() => {
                                                                        setColor(value.value)
                                                                        validate(value.value)
                                                                    }}>
                                                                        {value.value}
                                                                    </Button>
                                                                }
                                                            </div>
                                                        )
                                                    }
                                                })
                                            )
                                        }
                                    })}
                                </Row>
                            }
                            {product && product.options &&
                                <Row>
                                    <div>
                                        <select onChange={(e) => setSize(e.target.value)}>
                                            <option value="Selecciona">Selecciona</option>
                                            {product.options.map(option => {
                                                if (option.option === 'size') {
                                                    return (
                                                        option.values.map((value, id) => {
                                                            return (
                                                                <option 
                                                                    key={id} 
                                                                    value={value.value} 
                                                                >{value.value}</option>
                                                            )
                                                        }) 
                                                    )
                                                }
                                            })}
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </Row>
                            }
                            <Row>
                                <div>
                                    <ReactKeyboardEventHandler
                                        handleKeys={['enter']}
                                        onKeyEvent={() => addTocart()}
                                    >
                                        <input 
                                            name="qty"
                                            value={qty}
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                            type="number"
                                        />
                                    </ReactKeyboardEventHandler>
                                </div>
                            </Row>
                            <Row>
                                {msgQty !== '' && <span>{msgQty}</span>}
                            </Row>
                        </Table>
                    </SpecsContainer>
                </InfoSpecsContainer>

                <ButtonsContainer>
                    <button>Regresar</button>
                    <button onClick={() => addTocart()}>Agregar al carrito</button>
                </ButtonsContainer>

            </ElementsContainer>
        </>
    )
}

export {PurchaseSection}
```

Comment: Lo que te recomiendo principalmente es investigar sobre tipos de productos (con propiedades comunes), crear una columna `product_type` en tu tabla y así crear componentes personalizados para uno o saber que cada tipo tendrá ciertas propiedades que otros no. Siempre debes buscar la homogeneidad en ese aspecto. Te recomiendo usar TypeScript para mapear los tipos en interfaces para ser más cuidadoso con eso.

Comment: Hola Jonatan. Muchas gracias, muy valiosa tu recomendación ya que me estás dando una solución que tú implementarías. En síntesis, lo que me mencionas es que, por cada tipo de producto debería crear un componente con sus respectivas propiedades, ¿correcto?. Ahora bien dado que tú recomendación es muy buena, te realizaré otra pregunta, eso serviría muy bien para una ecommerce de varias categorías, peor si solo me centro en vender ropa deportiva, ¿debería tener un solo componente, y un panel de control que se adapte solo a ello, es decir, sin necesidad de opciones para otros productos?. Gracias.

Comment: La mayoría de productos tienen propiedades similares, dudo mucho que obtengas más de dos tipos de productos (no hablo de categorías). Lo importante aquí es mapearlos utilizando interfaces con TypeScript. Y respecto a tu pregunta, lo ideal es sólo tener 1 componente para todos los producto, pero si presentas demasiadas diferencias, lo mejor es optar por abstraerlos por tipos. Y con eso dicho, en mi opinión, necesitarías sólo uno.

Comment: Correctamente, el punto es que, por ejemplo, en el case de vender ropa, las propiedades serían talla y color, y dicha información vendría de la base de datos, lo cual no sería lo mismo para el caso de vender electrodomésticos, he aquí mi última pregunta, ¿cómo se procedería en dicho caso?. De antemano, muchas gracias Jonatan.

Comment: Los electrodomésticos también tienen color y tamaños (size), pero entiendo a lo que te refieres. En ese caso, simplemente debes aislar las propiedades desde la base de datos. Por ejemplo, puedes tener propiedades comunes como `price`, `name`, `url`, `attributes`, `hasColors`, `hasSizes`, esas propiedades como "`hasColors`" deberían ser boolean para que sepas qué propiedades vendrán y cuales no, y poder actuar acorde en el fron-end. Las opciones de solución son muchas, solo es cuestión de abstracción. Espero haber sido de ayuda, suerte.

Comment: Excelente, una vez mencionado lo anterior, ¿debería tener estados por cada una de las opciones de los productos?, es decir, un estado para color, size, qty, etc; los cuales seleccionará a el usuario. Así como tengo establecido en mi código.